# Directive contains transculde with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a template as following header, body(ng-transclude), footer

```
<div class="wfm-modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" id="close-button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()" aria-label="Close"
                ng-show="allowClose">
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
    </div>

    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="button-row text-right">
            <!-- Save button -->
            <button id="save" type="submit" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span ng-if="saveLabel">
                    {{saveLabel}}
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a wfm-modal which contains header body(which is ng-transclude) and footer.

My directive:

```
app

.directive('wfmModal', function ($window, $timeout, _, $log, $compile, $templateCache) {
    'use strict';


    var link = function (scope, element, attr, controller, transclude) {

        transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
            element.empty();
            element.append(clone);
        });

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link,
        templateUrl: 'directives/wfmModal/wfmModal.tpl.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '=',
            allowClose: '=',
            cancel: '=',
            save: '=',
            saveLabel: '@',

            delete: '='
            //delete: '=',
            //deletePopover: '@'
        }
    };
})
```

My problem: when I dont add the

```
transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
                element.empty();
                element.append(clone);
            });
```

to link function then the scope of the body(the content of ng-transclude) is empty on the save that done from the footer(the directive) not from the code of the ng-transclude

when I add this transclude(scope, function...) without the line: `element.empty();` then the body the content of ng-transclude is duplicated,
when I add `element.empty();` then the header and the footer are disappeared and only the content of ng-transculde is displayed.

I want to connect the scope of ng-transclude to the directive's scope without disrupt the UI

Answer (score 0):

In directive's link function add:

```
link = function (scope, element, attr, controller, transclude) {
  transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        var el = element.find('.wfmBody');
        el.append(clone);
    });
```

In html file instead of ng-transclude add:

```
<div class="wfmBody"></div>
```